# C program - largest word in a 2d array string

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

I'm currently tackling string programs. The program works if I input all strings of a specific size to the same length. For e.g. "Sat Sun Say" will output "min=Sat, max=Sun". However, if I input "Sat Sun Say Some", it doesn't output "min=Sat, max=Some" as expected. Any ideas?

```
void minMaxString(char word[][40], char *min, char *max, int size)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < strlen(word[j]); j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(word[i]); i++) {
            if (strcmp(word[i], word[j]) < 0) {
                strcpy(min, word[i]);
            } else if (strcmp(word[i], word[j]) > 0) {
                strcpy(max, word[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to that the parameter size is not used in the function.:) Think about how to use it.:)

Comment: Post the code that calls `minMaxString()` and does the "program works if I input all strings ..."

Comment: What do you mean by "largets"? Is "small" larger than "tiny"?

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks! I figured out that I have to add on strlen to check the length of each word[i] and word[j].